# Allow user to login with different account other than active session in OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to implement an app which will allow user to register with different emails like gmail, yahoo, outlook etc. For this i am implementing with help of OAuth.

My use case is if user logs in with one email account in browser and comes to my application to register. Then i want to allow the user to register with other email account which is not active in browser. Now i am getting that option. It is directly taking whatever active session in browser and asking him to grant access. User may not want to login with same account. So i am looking for this option. Any idea how can i configure?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with my application.  I need to catch a difference between the logged in user session and a previously logged in GAPI JS client from another user.  From what I can tell, the API comes up a little short when it comes to actually getting any useful session information.  (Mostly I'm using this comment to get SO to track your thread so I remember to check if you managed to solve it).  Good luck.

Comment: User can signout in the intermediate oauth page and sign into another page. Then it will grant permission to new account and redirect to our page with access credentials of new account. But it is that much straight forward for users to identify that feature